# Filtering column results based on list values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter out some rows in a dataframe where the Category Row includes one of the items from my list.

It works with exact matches, but not if there is more than one category associated with a record.

**For example:**

| ID | Categories | Date | Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01.01.2020 | alfa |
| 2 | B | 01.01.2020 | beta |
| 3 | C | 01.01.2020 | nick |
| 4 | A, C | 01.01.2020 | ray |
| 5 | A, B | 01.01.2020 | john |
| 6 | B, C | 01.01.2020 | smith |

So I try to use the following code:

```
exclude_list = ['A', 'C']
df = df[~df['Categories'].isin(exclude_list)]
```

this gives me

| ID | Categories | Date | Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | B | 01.01.2020 | beta |
| 4 | A, C | 01.01.2020 | ray |
| 5 | A, B | 01.01.2020 | john |
| 6 | B, C | 01.01.2020 | smith |

The 'Categories' where A and C are both present is still showing in the DF. I want to only show those Categories where A and C are *not* present.

I also tried to add variations such as ',A' 'A' 'A,' - but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test by substrings if possible:

```
exclude_list = ['A', 'C']
df1 = df[~df['Categories'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude_list))]
```

Another idea is explode values splitted by `,` and test with `isin` with `any` for match at least one value per index:

```
exclude_list = ['A', 'C']
df1 = df[~df['Categories'].str.split(', ').explode().isin(exclude_list).any(level=0)]
```

Last possible solution, with apply, so maybe slowier in real data:

```
df1 = df[~df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: any([y in exclude_list for y in x.split(', ')]))]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   ID Categories        Date Users
1   2          B  01.01.2020  beta
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you! How many hours I spent Googling and trying to figure this out!
You're a lifesaver